When I run the vs code this message is showing

extension bisect is active and has disabled 5 extensions. check if you can still reproduce the problem and proceed by selecting from these options. in vs code

I disabled all extension and re-enabled but the problem is still there.

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect try closing and reopening. (how did you open VS Code?)

Trying to reinstall vs code will solve your problem...

I tried many times but the issue remains same

Then do this,

Go to vs code > settings
Search : proxy ( and go to the proxy
settings page )
Scroll until you see "http: proxy
support"
Set it to fallback

Try this
